# create array with form data which groups and sorts data

Tags: jquery

I have some input fields than I want as an array so that I can view them in a table on my page. I have been able to create an array using [.serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/VNSam/3/) I have been able to output my array however I want the data to appear as it does in the table I have hard coded at the bottom of the fiddle, where it groups all the instances of Tom and Jerry into one row per id.  Accumalating all sales values for that id etc.  And I want to sort it by the total sale price column.  I am aware of server side techniques to do this however in this case I am looking for a jquery solution.  What is the best way to acheive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you can rely on the hidden input fields always appearing in groups of four with an `id[]`, `name[]`, `sales[]` & `price[]` for each group, otherwise (obviously) you can't tell which fields are related. So rather than use `.serializeArray()`, which returns a single array with all the values, I'd put the ids in their own array, the names in their own, and so forth. Perhaps something like this:

```
function showValues() {
    function getVal(el, i) {
        return el.value;
    }
    var ids = $.map($('input[name="id[]"]'), getVal),
        names = $.map($('input[name="name[]"]'), getVal),
        sales = $.map($('input[name="sales[]"]'), getVal),
        prices = $.map($('input[name="price[]"]'), getVal),
        data = {},
        i,
        $results = $("#results");

    for (i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
        if (!data[ids[i]]) {
            // if current id is new add a record for it:
            data[ids[i]] = {
                "id":ids[i],"name":names[i],"sales":+sales[i],"price":+prices[i]
            };
        } else {
            // otherwise add to existing record's totals
            data[ids[i]].sales += +sales[i];
            data[ids[i]].price += +prices[i];
        }
    }
    // data object now contains the details for each salesman,
    // so turn it into an array to allow sorting:
    data = $.map(data, function(val, key) { return val; });
    data.sort(function(a,b) { return a.price - b.price; });

    // now output table - assume there's already a table element with headings
    $.each(data, function(i, val) {
        var $tr = $("<tr></tr>").attr("data-id", val.id).appendTo($results);
        $("<td></td>").text(val.name).appendTo($tr);
        $("<td></td>").text(val.sales).appendTo($tr);
        $("<td></td>").text(val.price).appendTo($tr);
        $("<td></td>").text(val.price / 10).appendTo($tr);
    });
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/VNSam/5/

By way of explanation, this line:

```
ids = $.map($('input[name="id[]"]'), getVal)
```

...says to get all inputs with `name="id[]"`, and pass the resulting jQuery object to the [`$.map()` method](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) so that we can get back an array containing just the id values - you can see that `getVal()` is just a simple function that does exactly that. I do the same thing for `name[]` and the other fields.

Note also that the sales and price values are strings when retrieved from the inputs, so I'm using the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_%28Unary_Plus%29) to convert them to numbers.

Comment: Fantastic thanks! I didn't think .serializeArray() was the way to go, I wasn't to familiar with .map() so this is good to know.I want to sort by highest, so I can just change this to return b.price - a.price or add in data.reverse(); . One thing I don't understand is in the inital example which I based my fiddle on http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/VNSam/ you can update the field on select. When I have tried to build this functionality into what you have done I get 2 errors? 1. I get NAN and 2. it builds the results again instead of updating? Do you see why? http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/VNSam/6/

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/VNSam/7/ - 1. NaN was because my code assumed all the fields would be input elements (the first sentence of my answer stated as much), so by replacing one of the `name="price[]"` inputs with a select that meant the select was ignored and the `prices` array had one less value than the other arrays so the code was reading past the end of the array. Remove `input` from the jQuery selectors and just get fields based on their name and that problem goes away.

Comment: 2. My code assumed the table already existed and appended to the end of it. In the updated fiddle I've added a line `$results.find("tr[data-id]").remove();` to remove any rows added previously (you'll notice in my original solution I already set a `data-id` attribute, so that is a convenient way to select the rows that need to be replaced.

Comment: Thanks so simple to remove the input, I should have picked this up. I have tried to extend it further to make the commision 30% + 5 for each sale in http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/VNSam/8/ however want to be able to have a secondary sort (commision) + only 2 decimal places. I have tried something like var commish = '.text((val.price / 3) + (val.sales*5))'; and in the results $("<td></td>");commish.toFixed().appendTo($tr);  for the sort but can't get it working. Let me know if these additional problems shouldn't be in the comments and I will post a new question for this. thanks