# add secondary sort to array output

Tags: jquery

I have [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/VNSam/8/) which was based on the results from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813010/create-array-with-form-data-which-groups-and-sorts-data).  I am trying to extend this further so that I can add a secondary sort so that if total price is the same it then looks to the commission column and whoever has the highest commission will go on top where the total sale price is equal.  Is this possible?  I am also having trouble with getting the commision column to be 2 decimal places.  I have tried doing

```
var commish = '.text((val.price / 3) + (val.sales*5))';
```

and in the results section.

```
$("<td></td>");commish.toFixed(2).appendTo($tr);
```

But this has not worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Calculate the commission and store in the objects, so that you can use it both in the sorting and the display:

```
d.commission = d.price / 3 + d.sales * 5;
```

To sort on the commission secondary, check if the price is equal, and if it is return the comparison for the commission:

```
data.sort(function(a,b) {
  return a.price == b.price ? b.commission - a.commission : b.price - a.price;
});
```

When you have the commission in the object, it's easy to format it for display:

```
$("<td></td>").text(val.commission.toFixed(2)).appendTo($tr);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/VNSam/9/

Comment: I am having trouble extending this further. I am trying to use the same principles in this working example. http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/SDCkW/4/ so that when you select something from the dropdown it populates all relevant fields in the array see http://jsfiddle.net/aaronk85/VNSam/13/ but for some reason (i don't appear to get any errors) this is not working. Am I executing the code in the wrong place?

Comment: @ak85: You have put the `select` outside the `form`, so the selector `form select` doesn't apply to it.

Comment: i read that the `a - b` shortcut only works on numbers, not strings.